# Why is my Outlook Add-in silently failing the "onMessageSendHandler" action when side-loading from a static website?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've created a small Outlook Add-in using the Yeoman generator and I've developing it using Visual Studio Code.

The add-in only does two things:

1. When the `onNewMessageComposeHandler` action fires, it sets the email message's subject line to "Hello, World!"
2. When the `onMessageSendHandler` action fires, it adds an email address to the `To:` list of recipients.

This is the code in my `launchevents.js` file:

```
const bccRecipientEmail = "foo@bar.test";

function onMessageSendHandler(event) {
  setBcc(event);
  event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
}

function onNewMessageComposeHandler(event) {
  setSubject(event);
}

function setBcc(event) {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.addAsync(
    [bccRecipientEmail],
    {
      asyncContext: event,
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
      // Handle success or error.
      if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.error("Failed to set bcc to '" + bccRecipientEmail + "': " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
      }

      // Call event.completed() after all work is done.
      asyncResult.asyncContext.completed();
    }
  );
}

function setSubject(event) {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.setAsync(
    "Set by an event-based add-in! WITH COMPOSE",
    {
      asyncContext: event,
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
      // Handle success or error.
      if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.error("Failed to set subject: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
      }

      // Call event.completed() after all work is done.
      asyncResult.asyncContext.completed();
    }
  );
}

if (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null) {
  Office.actions.associate("onMessageSendHandler", onMessageSendHandler);
  Office.actions.associate("onNewMessageComposeHandler", onNewMessageComposeHandler);
}
```

These are the relevant parts from my `manifest.xml` file:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.12">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <!-- Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime.-->
        <Runtimes>
          <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
               This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI. -->
          <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
            <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
            <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
          </Runtime>
        </Runtimes>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            [...]
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Can configure other command surface extension points for add-in command support. -->

          <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included events. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
            <LaunchEvents>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onNewMessageComposeHandler"/>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
            </LaunchEvents>
            <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
            <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/taskpane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/commands.html" />
        <!-- Entry needed for Outlook on Windows. -->
        <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://[REDACTED].web.core.windows.net/launchevent.js" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Sync Emails to Quickbase"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

When I run the add-in on my machine and side-load it into Outlook on Windows<sup>1</sup>, it works well. I can see the subject line change when I compose the message and when I send it, the email address is indeed added to the recipients list.

Now I'm trying to publish my add-in to a static site in Azure Storage, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-add-in-vs-code#using-visual-studio-code-to-publish). When I side-load the add-in from the static site's URL I find that the subject line changes successfully but the email address is not added to the list of recipients.

**My question is - Why, when I side-load the add-in from a static site, does the `onMessageSendHandler` not work as expected?**

---

*<sup>1</sup> Outlook version: Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200) 64-bit*

Comment: How does your actual code look like? Could you be more specific? Is the `OnMessageSend` fired at all?

Comment: Thanks. The code in the handler make a single call to `Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.addAsync()`. The success callback runs `asyncResult.asyncContext.completed();`. I should stress that this *works* when side-loading from localhost. It only fails when side-loading from the Azure Storage static site. That is the what my question is about.

Comment: It does not give the full picture of your code.

Comment: @eugene-astafiev I've edited my question to include the code for the `onMessageSendHandler` action.

Comment: In the manifest I see two events declared in the same file, but  in the code only one event is presented.

Comment: Also, there is no need to call the `completed` method twice in the code, see my post for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add any logging statements to the events handlers, so you could see whether a particular event handler is invoked for sure.

Make sure that your code includes the following piece:

```
// IMPORTANT: To ensure your add-in is supported in the Outlook client on Windows, remember to map the event handler name specified in the manifest's LaunchEvent element to its JavaScript counterpart.
// 1st parameter: FunctionName of LaunchEvent in the manifest; 2nd parameter: Its implementation in this .js file.
if (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null) {
  Office.actions.associate("onNewMessageComposeHandler", onNewMessageComposeHandler);
  Office.actions.associate("OnMessageSend", onMessageSendHandler);
}
```

Event-based add-ins running in Outlook on Windows don't run code included in the `Office.onReady()` and `Office.initialize` functions. We recommend adding your add-in startup logic, such as checking the user's Outlook version, to your event handlers instead.

See [Implement event handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest#implement-event-handling) for more information about that.

Also try to find the add-in's `bundle.js` file, navigate to the following folder in `File Explorer`. Replace text enclosed in `[]` with your applicable Outlook and add-in information.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\{[Outlook profile GUID]}\[Outlook mail account encoding]\Javascript\[Add-in ID]_[Add-in Version]_[locale]
```

Open `bundle.js` in Visual Studio Code and check the source code.

---

In the source code I've noticed that the `completed` method is called from the `setAsync` callback. That is not required at all. See [Get, set, or add recipients when composing an appointment or message in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-set-or-add-recipients) for more information how to set up recipients.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've already tried all of these, to no avail. Perhaps you can elaborate on how I can read the logging statements when the add-in runs? I've not been able to directly debug it, I'm afraid, as I've asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351926/what-is-the-right-launch-configuration-to-debug-an-event-based-outlook-add-in

Comment: @urig Please see this documentation for more information on logging/debugging an Outlook add-in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging