# What is the right launch configuration to debug an event-based Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, vscode-debugger, outlook-web-addins

I am coding a Yeoman-generated Outlook add-in that runs event-based code. Specifically, the add-in uses the `onMessageSendHandler` action to make slight modifications to outgoing email messages.

I am following the official instructions to "[debug your event-based Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch)" in Visual Studio Code. I find that consistently, **no breakpoints that I set on my code are ever caught**. This includes any breakpoints set on my `onMessageSendHandler` action code.

The instructions above provide the following Visual Studio Code launch configuration to use in `launch.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Direct Debugging",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "port": 9223,
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "timeout": 600000,
  "trace": true
}
```

This bit of code has two issues:

1. In many places, instead of a single space character, an invisible `U+202f` character is present.
2. The `"protocol"` property is marked as not allowed in my Visual Studio Code (v1.78.2).

[image: Screen shot of the above launch configuration code with a warning overlaid by Visual Studio Code. The warning says "Property protocol is not allowed".]

Having fixed issue #1, my question is **might issue #2 be the reason my breakpoints are not caught?** How can I fix things so that my breakpoints - specifically inside the event action - are caught?

---

###### Diagnostic details

- Windows 10
- Node.js 18.16.0
- Visual Studio Code 1.78.2
- Packages installed in VS Code:

  ```
  dbaeumer.vscode-eslint@2.4.0
  esbenp.prettier-vscode@9.13.0
  ms-azuretools.vscode-azureresourcegroups@0.7.5
  ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestorage@0.15.2
  ms-azuretools.vscode-docker@1.25.1
  ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools@2.1.1
  ms-python.isort@2022.8.0
  ms-python.python@2023.8.0
  ms-python.vscode-pylance@2023.5.40
  ms-toolsai.jupyter@2023.4.1011241018
  ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap@1.1.0
  ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers@1.0.15
  ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags@0.1.8
  ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow@0.1.5
  ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers@0.292.0
  ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl@0.78.8
  ms-vscode.azure-account@0.11.5
  ms-vscode.powershell@2023.5.0
  NilsSoderman.batch-runner@1.0.1
  redhat.vscode-xml@0.25.0
  ```

Comment: What is the NodeJS version used on your machine?

Comment: Windows and Outlook versions?

Answer (score 1):

When started with the inspector protocol like shown in the `launch.json` file, a Node.js process listens for a debugging client (forces the node debugger to use the `inspector` protocol based implementation). It is supported by the following versions:

```
node.js < 8.x | >= 6.3 (Windows: >= 6.9)
```

Also you may find the [Protocol: "inspector" inside launch.json is ignored](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57943) post helpful.

Note, to be able to debug launch events you need to [Attach the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch?tabs=windows#attach-the-debugger) and then [Run the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch?tabs=windows#run-the-debugger).

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Much appreciated. I've tried these again and still the breakpoints do not work. I can add two observations: 1. The `bundles.js` appears as a single, long line. I am only able to place a single breakpoint in its very start (aside from breakpoints that I've set in `launchevent.js` and 2. the debugger session stops as soon as I click "OK" on the "Debug Event-based handler" dialog. That's not normal is it?

Comment: I've read through the "protocol: inspector inside launch.json is ignored" issue that you've linked to. It mentions two VS Code extensions ("Node Debug" and "Node Debug(Legacy)") that are now deprecated and are not installed in my instance. Might this have something to do with the launch configuration seeming to fail for me?

Comment: Do you have any other extensions enabled?

Comment: Your nodejs version installed on the machine?

Comment: tx. I added the details you asked for to the question.

Comment: I don't have most of these extensions installed and got breakpoints hit when I try to debug launch events in Outlook. Try to disable extensions and see whether it helps.